# Kubernetes - Accessing a ClusterIP service using Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I've had my services set with type `NodePort` however in reality external access it not required - they only need to be able to talk to each other.

Therefore I presume I should change these to the default `ClusterIP` however the question is - how can I continue to access these services during my local development?

So when i make the change from `NodePort` to `ClusterIP` then go to `minikube service list` it naturally shows `no node port` however how can I now access - is there some special endpoint address I can get from somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You would need to access it like any other out-of-cluster case. Generally this means either `kubectl port-forward` or `kubectl proxy`, I favor the former though. In general, ClusterIP services are only accessible from inside the cluster, accessing through forwarders is only used for debugging or infrequent access.

Comment: Ok - and otherwise, am I correct to actually think I should be switching them from `NodePort` to `ClusterIP`? I'm assuming this is the recommended best practice?

Comment: Also, I'm able to use port forward and access the service: `kubectl port-forward mygreatservice-94fc44965-pbbtg 3000:3000 -n my-namespace`
However I have 10 of these services. Is there a more convenient way to do this?

Comment: Is this a service that is expected to be used only within the cluster or accessed from the outside?

Comment: Accessed within the cluster

Comment: Then yes, use clusterip

Answer (score 3):

Since you have 10 such services, I believe using an Ingress Controller will be a better option here. I have worked on a similar scenario, where we would want to access our services directly in local or QA environment and not in Production.

We used [Nginx Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/). You may get more details about ingress [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). It was fairly simple to setup and well served the purpose.

Thanks!

Comment: So I just setup traefik and looks like that may help. So just to check, for your testing purposes, you have say a 'development ingress file' which you apply to give you access to all your services. Then in production, you wouldn't want those services exposed openly, so you don't apply that ingress?

Comment: @userMod2 Yes. We would have ingress only for publicly exposed services.